# ANDROID - How to compare URL with string

Tags: java, android, url

So recently i wanted to add comparing code for my application, that grabs text from URL (pastebin - raw) and compares it to string that i give it to him. I found code but how do i make the result from the URL to the string so that i can use it later?

My goal:
What I'm trying to do is that I want to create my own update check. It simply takes the version from pastebin, so I can change it at any time, and there is a string in the app where the current version of the app is. If that version isn't the same, then when I turn it on it creates a dialog saying that a new version is out and gives a link to download it.

Code:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.snippets.core;
 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
 
public class ReadTextFromURL {
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        try {
             
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com:80/");
             
            // read text returned by server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
             
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
             
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
         
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your request correctly you want to get the HTML String of a pastebin page. Here is how you could do it:

```
static class RetrieveHTMLStringTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private String result = "";
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return "";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO: do something with the HTML-String
            System.out.println(this.result);
        }
    }
```

then execute this task somewhere, like this:

```
RetrieveHTMLStringTask().execute("your url")
```

Answer (score 0):

so you just want to compare two sets of string-based data?

```
    String savedInappString = "xyz";
    URL url1 = new URL("https://www.test.com");
    System.out.println("The given url is : "+url1);
```

//output is "The given url is : https://www.test.com"

```
    if(savedInappString.equals(url1)){
        //don't update
    }else {
        //give update dialog
    }
```

//        if this gives error create a string variable of url like mentioned below
String urlStr = url1.toString();

```
    if (savedInappString.equals(urlStr)){
        //don't update
    }else {
        //give update dialog
    }
```

Hope this answers your issue.